# Manual implement a timeout task future in rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Function description, there is an async task, if the signal is received within 10s, the task can continue to execute, otherwise cancel; if the task has been executed within 10s, then nothing will be done.

1. The following code has a compilation problem, how to fix;
2. Whether it can be optimized (the status of ready is query twice actually)

```rust
struct MyFuture {
    timeout: tokio::time::Timeout<Receiver<()>>,
    task: Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Unpin>,
    ready: Option<bool>,
}

impl MyFuture {
    fn new(
        receiver: Receiver<()>,
        duration: Duration,
        task: Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Unpin>,
    ) -> Self {
        let timeout = tokio::time::timeout(duration, receiver);
        Self {
            timeout,
            task,
            ready: None,
        }
    }
}

impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match Pin::new(&mut self.task).poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(_) => Poll::Ready(()),
            Poll::Pending => match self.ready {
                Some(true) => Poll::Pending,
                Some(false) => Poll::Ready(()),
                // !!! compile error here
                None => match Pin::new(&mut self.timeout).poll(cx) {
                    Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
                    Poll::Ready(r) => {
                        if r.is_err() {
                            // timeout and cancel task
                            self.ready = Some(false);
                            Poll::Ready(())
                        } else {
                            // receive signal and wait task finished
                            self.ready = Some(true);
                            Poll::Pending
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

[The full code's playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ba5c4f52d7ba246dd46d70fb784c9d0)

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Yes that also requires you to specify the (mis-)behavior of the crurrent attempt including a complete compile error or runtime expected vs actual behavior.

Comment: `tokio::time::Timeout<Receiver<()>>` doesn't make any sense, I know no `Receiver` that implements `Future` is it a custom type of yours?

Comment: @cafce25 I have add the playground link, and the `Receiver` type is `tokio::sync::oneshot::Receiver`

Comment: Please add the MRE *within* the post, a playground link while appreciated is not sufficient as the external resource might not be available everywhere.

Comment: I think your problems can be solved by properly `Pin`ing `timeout` and `task` in `MyFuture`

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the task with `Timeout`? This is exactly its intended purpose.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman task may continue run after timeout

Comment: It won't. The future will be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

After asking chatgpt, I change the **MyFuture** structure:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct MyFuture {
    #[pin]
    timeout: tokio::time::Timeout<Receiver<()>>,
    #[pin]
    task: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>,
    ready: Option<bool>,
}
```

and the poll function:

```rust
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut task::Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        info!("poll");
        let this = self.project();

        match this.task.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(_) => {
                info!("poll and task done");
                Poll::Ready(())
            }
            Poll::Pending => match this.ready {
                None => {
                    info!("poll and not ready");
                    match this.timeout.poll(cx) {
                        Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
                        Poll::Ready(r) => {
                            if r.is_err() {
                                info!("poll and timeout");
                                // timeout and cancel task
                                *(this.ready) = Some(false);
                                Poll::Ready(())
                            } else {
                                info!("poll and recv ready");
                                // receive signal and wait task finished
                                *(this.ready) = Some(true);
                                Poll::Pending
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Some(true) => {
                    info!("poll and ready");
                    Poll::Pending
                }
                Some(false) => Poll::Ready(()),
            },
        }
    }
```

Now it work. The root cause is the understanding of **Future** and **poll** is not deep enough.